# Output based on variable

Tags: c++

I am in an intro to Computer science course learning C++. Our current project involves taking input of what type of bank account the person has (commercial or personal) and following different paths for both. I have found that this would cause me to write two output functions, one for each different type of account.

Would there be a way for me to write 1 output function but have it output the information based on what type of account they chose?

For example what I was thinking of would be to give each choice a number. This example would be personal is 0 and Commercial is 1. When they enter what type it assigned the number 1 or 0 to a variable and then each variable I output would be based off a if statement that says if X is equal to 1 then output Y if not output Z.

Any help would be appreciated and if this is unclear I can provide more information about the project.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can definitely do that, really simply.  Just implement what you've described above, and it should work.

Comment: In a professional quality application, you would implement this requirement using something called the "Template Design Pattern". But that is a bit too advanced at this stage. Just take a note of it for now, do what you describe above, and once you have learned object-oriented programming to a high standard, revisit this question and google and read about this design pattern and see how you would implement your solution that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a template to help you get started:

```
enum AccountType { Checking, Savings };

void Output( AccountType userAccount )
{
  switch ( userAccount )
  {
     case Checking:
     // do something here for checking accounts
     break;
     case Savings:
     // do something here for savings accounts
     break;
  }
}
```

There are definitely other ways, but this is simple to understand.

Comment: Thanks that is a lot simpler of a way for me to do this! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there certainly is such a way to do that. Without needing to make separate classes for CommercialAccounts and PersonalAccounts, inheritance, et cetera, you can just do

```
#define COMMERCIAL 0
#define PERSONAL 1

void printAccount(int account_type /* add parameters for the actual account data */) {
  switch(account_type) {
  case COMMERCIAL:
    // do stuff...
    break;
  case PERSONAL:
    //do stuff...
    break;
  default:
    std::cerr << "Error: " /* invalid input error message */ << std:: endl;
  }
}
```